# Applying a change to all changes in a git commit

Tags: git

I am not sure that what I want is possible, but basically I did a commit to my app where I changed some occurrences of "\\" to "/" let's call this **Commit 1**. 
 but now a want to change all of these occurrences from "/" to "$$", so I want to apply a change to the changes that happened in commit 1 only without altering any of the occurrences of "\\" that was not changed to "/" in commit 1

Comment: What's the issue of replacing `/` to `$$`? Shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: There are a lot of other `/` that I do not want to change it to  `$$` I want to change only the ones which were changed from \\ to /

Comment: How many changes (individual `\\ -> /` changes) are we talking about ?

Comment: @LeGEC about a thousand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to get clever :

if your changes occurred at commit `B` :

```
...*--*--*--A--B--*--*--H <- master
```

Running :

- `git diff B A` will produce a patch that would replace `/` with `\\` (e.g : revert commit `B`),
- `git diff B A -G'/'` will only keep the files where the diff includes a `/` (so with some luck, it will reduce the size of the generated diff).

You can try to :

1. store that diff in a file :

```
git diff B A -G'/' > my.patch
```

2. edit that file in a text editor, to turn it from a patch which replaces `/` with `\\` to a patch which replaces `/` with `$$`
3. apply this edited patch on your current code base :

```
git apply my.patch
```

Depending on how the other changes were applied after commit `B`, the number of generated conflics may be reasonable to handle by hand.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant about getting clever! :) And now that we know there are a thousand of these, I think clever is better!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is the simple-minded manual way. Do a diff between `commit1` and its parent. Now you have a list of all the lines where you changed `"\\`" to `"/"`. Using that list as a guide, change the `"/"` in each of those lines to `"$$"`. Add-and-commit.

<sub>(It is possible to get clever about this and make a patch which you can modify into the patch you need, and apply it, but it's probably not worth the trouble unless there are a lot of affected files.)</sub>